# Is there validation in Spring boot at the method parameter level in the Rest API?

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I would like to validate the data even before it is processed on the service layer.

- dto

```java
@Validated
public class DataDto {


    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    String keyId;
```

I would like that when **Jackson** starts converting json to dto, then paying attention to the annotations above the DTO fields of the object, it would send a response with errors

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(API_V3)
@Validated
public class DataRestController {

    @PostMapping(path = "data")
    public ResponseEntity<DataDto>
    createNewModelBasedUploadFile(@RequestBody @Valid List<DataDto> modelList) {

   }
```

Note that I'm validating a collection of values here.

I also set this up

```java
@Configuration
public class ValidConfig {
    @Bean
    MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Validation does not occur.

Maybe you still need to write your own validator ?
But how can I connect and configure it here ?

I have looked through many such questions here and on the net. But I didn't find a solution. Basically, all validation occurs when an entity is trying to save to the database....

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

### **Update**

Let's summarize:

**1.@Vaidated** - must be installed over a RestController.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(API_V3)
@Validated
public class DataRestController {
}
```

**2.@Valid** - must be installed near a type of Collection

```java
createNewModelBasedUploadFile(@RequestBody List<@Valid DataDto> modelList) 
   {

   }
```

**3.@Validated** - don't need over Java dto-object.

**4.Java dto-object** - must have any annotation for validation above self fields.

```java
public class DataDto {


    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    String keyId;
}
```

**5.- pom.xml**

I don't point that dependency

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

but, into the **pom.xml** has :

```xml
  <dependency>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**6.The config file**  - don't need also.

```java
@Configuration
public class ValidConfig {
    @Bean
    MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
createNewModelBasedUploadFile(@RequestBody List<@Valid DataDto> modelList)
```